# How do I update information on the database using JQUERY sortable list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I've just started using Jquery UI and I ran into a problem.

I got 5 lists getting printed through a PHP function (called 4 times), and I just made them sortable between themselves, the problem is, I want to be able to drag elements between them, and as I drag them, I need to update the field "week", that corresponds to in which list the element will be.

Now, I've tried simply updating the 'week' to the id of the table (conveniently numbered 1 through 5), but I know of no way to retrieve the element's id inside the list so I can update the right field of the right element.

That's some snippets of my code:

**HTML code**

```
<div class="row">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field center col s2" style="margin-left: 5%; text-align: center">
        <ul class="collapsible">
          <li id = "1">
            <div class="collapsible-header">
              <i class="material-icons">update</i>
              Semana 01
              <span class="badge"><?php count_week($conn,$id,1); ?></span></div>
              <?php select_week_no_token($conn,$id,1); ?>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field center col s2" style="margin-left: 35px">
        <ul class="collapsible">
          <li  id = "2">
            <div class="collapsible-header">
              <i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
              Semana 02
              <span class="badge"><?php count_week($conn,$id,2); ?></span></div>
              <?php select_week_no_token($conn,$id,2); ?>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

All the way through week 5.

**PHP function code**

```
function select_week_no_token($conn,$id,$week)
{
    $query = "SELECT id,task,status FROM onboarding_checklist_week WHERE id_project='$id' AND week = $week";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        if($row['status'] == 1)
        {
            echo '<li><div style="background-color: #a7ffeb; padding:0" class="collapsible-body"><p>'.$row['task'].'</p></div></li>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<li><div style="background-color: #ffcdd2; padding:0" class="collapsible-body"><p>'.$row['task'].'</p></div></li>';
        }
    }
}
```

That's the function that prints the elements inside the table.
**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#1').sortable({
        cancel: ".collapsible-header",
        connectWith: '#2, #3, #4, #5',
        receive: function (event,ui) {
            var id = $(ui.item).attr('id');
            var week = '1';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'changeEvents.ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'id' : id,
                    'week': week
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#2').sortable({
        cancel: ".collapsible-header",
        connectWith: '#1, #3, #4, #5',
        receive: function (event,ui) {
            var id = $(ui.item).attr('id');
            var week = '2';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'changeEvents.ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'id' : id,
                    'week': week
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#3').sortable({
        cancel: ".collapsible-header",
        connectWith: '#2, #1, #4, #5',
        receive: function (event,ui) {
            var id = $(ui.item).attr('id');
            var week = '3';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'changeEvents.ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'id' : id,
                    'week': week
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#4').sortable({
        cancel: ".collapsible-header",
        connectWith: '#2, #3, #1, #5',
        receive: function (event,ui) {
            var id = $(ui.item).attr('id');
            var week = '4';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'changeEvents.ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'id' : id,
                    'week': week
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#5').sortable({
        cancel: ".collapsible-header",
        connectWith: '#2, #3, #4, #1',
        receive: function (event,ui) {
            var id = $(ui.item).attr('id');
            var week = '5';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'changeEvents.ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'id' : id,
                    'week': week
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

And here's the selectable javascript file, that I'm importing.

Basically, as of right now, I can get the list to be sortable, but cannot update it at all, it doesn't even calls to the function, and even if it did, I'm sure there'd be no way to update, since I don't have the 'id' field from my database corresponding to the element I'm dragging around.

Is there any way, easy or hard, to fix this? What is there wrong on the code and how can I retrieve such id, even if I have to use another coding language or something?

Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Ok, not a answer, but jQuery will be obsolete in the near future, you may want to learn Vue.js or React, they are much easier to code.

Comment: Well, I'm using Jquery because it's the solution I found, if you could present some kind of solution in vue.js or react, I could use that too, no problem!

Comment: I've presented to you, or pointed you at the right direction, the choice is yours. Like i did say, Vues.js or React.js are the way you want to go. Requires learning, but it will be worth!